# C++ Creating a Linked List With More Than 2 Fields per Node

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, iteration, nodes

So I am attempting to create a Linked List that can store books for a imaginative library. Within the linked list, each node should contain the branch of library, the author's name, the book's title, and the number of copies of said book.

I'm having difficulty creating a linked list with multiple fields per node. How would I go about it so that each node can store 3 separate strings and an integer, and then finally, a pointer to the next node?

Here is my current code.

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T element;  
    Node<T>* next; 

    Node() 
    {
        next = nullptr;
    }

    Node(T element) // Constructor
    {
        this->element = element;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
{
public:
    Iterator(Node<T>* p)
    {
        current = p;
    }

    Iterator operator++() // Prefix ++
    {
        current = current->next;
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int dummy) // Postfix ++
    {
        Iterator temp(current);
        current = current->next;
        return temp;
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return current->element;
    }

    bool operator==(const Iterator<T>& iterator)
    {
        return current == iterator.current;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Iterator<T>& iterator)
    {
        return current != iterator.current;
    }

private:
    Node<T>* current;
};

template<typename T>

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& list);
    virtual ~LinkedList();
    void addFirst(T element);
    void addLast(T element);
    T getFirst() const;
    T getLast() const;
    T removeFirst() throw (runtime_error);
    T removeLast();
    void add(T element);
    void add(int index, T element);
    void clear();
    bool contains(T element) const;
    T get(int index) const;
    int indexOf(T element) const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int lastIndexOf(T element) const;
    void remove(T element);
    int getSize() const;
    T removeAt(int index);
    T set(int index, T element);

    Iterator<T> begin() const
    {
        return Iterator<T>(head);
    }

    Iterator<T> end() const
    {
        return Iterator<T>(tail->next);
    }

private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    int size;
};

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    head = tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& list)
{
    head = tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;

    Node<T>* current = list.head;
    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        this->add(current->element);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    clear();
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addFirst(T element)
{
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(element);
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
    size++;

    if (tail == nullptr)
        tail = head;
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addLast(T element)
{
    if (tail == nullptr)
    {
        head = tail = new Node<T>(element);
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = new Node<T>(element);
        tail = tail->next;
    }

    size++;
}

template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::getFirst() const
{
    if (size == 0)
        throw runtime_error("Index out of range");
    else
        return head->element;
}

template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::getLast() const
{
    if (size == 0)
        throw runtime_error("Index out of range");
    else
        return tail->element;
}

template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::removeFirst() throw (runtime_error)
{
    if (size == 0)
        throw runtime_error("No elements in the list");
    else
    {
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        if (head == nullptr) tail = nullptr;
        size--;
        T element = temp->element;
        delete temp;
        return element;
    }
}

template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::removeLast()
{
    if (size == 0)
        throw runtime_error("No elements in the list");
    else if (size == 1)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        head = tail = nullptr;
        size = 0;
        T element = temp->element;
        delete temp;
        return element;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T>* current = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 2; i++)
            current = current->next;

        Node<T>* temp = tail;
        tail = current;
        tail->next = nullptr;
        size--;
        T element = temp->element;
        delete temp;
        return element;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::add(T element)
{
    addLast(element);
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::add(int index, T element)
{
    if (index == 0)
        addFirst(element);
    else if (index >= size)
        addLast(element);
    else
    {
        Node<T>* current = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++)
            current = current->next;
        Node<T>* temp = current->next;
        current->next = new Node<T>(element);
        (current->next)->next = temp;
        size++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear()
{
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::get(int index) const
{
    if (index < 0 || index > size - 1)
        throw runtime_error("Index out of range");

    Node<T>* current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        current = current->next;

    return current->element;
}

template<typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::indexOf(T element) const
{
    // Implement it in this exercise
    Node<T>* current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (current->element == element)
            return i;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return -1;
}

template<typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return head == nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::getSize() const
{
    return size;
}

template<typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::removeAt(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw runtime_error("Index out of range");
    else if (index == 0)
        return removeFirst();
    else if (index == size - 1)
        return removeLast();
    else
    {
        Node<T>* previous = head;

        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++)
        {
            previous = previous->next;
        }

        Node<T>* current = previous->next;
        previous->next = current->next;
        size--;
        T element = current->element;
        delete current;
        return element;
    }
}

// The functions remove(T element), lastIndexOf(T element),
// contains(T element), and set(int index, T element) are
// left as an exercise

#endif
```

Comment: Are you asking what `T` should be in `node<T>`?  How about a struct?

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm relatively new to C++, wouldn't T work  node<t> considering the type is dictated by whatever type is put into the node? 

And how would a struct change things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a struct, such as

```
struct Book
{
    std::string branch;
    std::string author;
    std::string title;
    int copies;
};
```

A `LinkedList<Book>` would have all the data elements you want in each `Node`.